# PostgreSQL : stored procedure can't be found

Tags: c#, postgresql

This is my postgresql stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE administer_charge(totalCost dec,smsLogId bigint,broadcastId int, singleDispatchId int, isBroadcast boolean, userId text,idempotencyToken text,smsStatus int,externalSMSId text, errorText text) 
language plpgsql
as $$
declare  
begin 
        
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM "SMSLogs" s where "IdempotencyToken" =idempotencyToken) THEN
         return;
        END IF;

        update "SMSLogs" set
        "Cost"=totalCost,
        "IdempotencyToken" =idempotencyToken,
         "SMSStatusId" =smsStatus,
         "ExternalId" =externalSMSId,
         "Error" =errorText
        where "SMSLogId" =smsLogId;
        
       IF(isBroadcast) THEN
         update "Broadcasts" set
         "TotalCost" ="TotalCost"+ totalCost,
            "TotalDelivered"="TotalDelivered"+CASE smsStatus
    WHEN 1 THEN 1
    else 0
    END,
             "TotalUndelivered"= "TotalUndelivered"+CASE smsStatus
    when 3 THEN 1
    else 0 END
          where "BroadcastId" =broadcastId;
        else 
          update "SingleDispatches" set
         "TotalCost"  = "TotalCost"+ totalCost, 
            "TotalDelivered"="TotalDelivered"+CASE smsStatus
    WHEN 1 THEN 1
    else 0
    END,
             "TotalUndelivered"= "TotalUndelivered"+CASE smsStatus
    when 3 THEN 1
    else 0 END
          where "SingleDispatchId" =singleDispatchId;
         end if;
        
        update "AspNetUsers"
        set "Balance" ="Balance"- totalCost
        where "Id" =userId;
       
     commit;
end; $$
```

This is how I execute it:

```
          using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connection.PostgreSqlConnection))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("administer_charge", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("totalCost", this.totalSMSCost);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("smsLogId", this.SMSLogId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("broadcastId", BroadCastId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("singleDispatchId", BroadCastId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("isBroadcast", IsBroadCast);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userId", this.receiverPhone.ApplicationUserId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idempotencyToken", idempotencyToken);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("smsStatus", smsStatus);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("externalSMSId", smsSid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("errorText", error ?? String.Empty);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
```

This is the error that I get

```
42883: function administer_charge(totalCost => numeric, smsLogId => integer, broadcastId => integer, singleDispatchId => integer, isBroadcast => boolean, userId => text, idempotencyToken => text, smsStatus => integer, externalSMSId => text, errorText => text) does not exist
```

If I make such a call in the database query explorer:

```
call administer_charge(12,44,24, 23, true, '5c7b2ac0-d55d-4066-9b76-8998753ab834','9537',1,'2223334', 'mY-ERR3OR');
```

It works.

I tried to read about a few solutions online, and reading their documentation. Nothing has worked.

```
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html
```

I tried to specify specific type by adding it to the parameter, but the error hasn't changed. Is the fault with the type, I suspect it could be with the parameter 'totalCost dec', but I am not sure.

UPDATE:
I made the following modification:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("totalCost", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value=  this.totalSMSCost;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("smsLogId", NpgsqlDbType.Bigint) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value = this.SMSLogId; 
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("broadcastId", NpgsqlDbType.Integer) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value = BroadCastId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("singleDispatchId", NpgsqlDbType.Integer) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value = BroadCastId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("isBroadcast", NpgsqlDbType.Boolean) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value = IsBroadCast;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("userId", NpgsqlDbType.Text) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value = this.receiverPhone.ApplicationUserId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("idempotencyToken", NpgsqlDbType.Text) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value = idempotencyToken;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("smsStatus", NpgsqlDbType.Integer) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value = smsStatus; 
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("externalSMSId", NpgsqlDbType.Text) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value = smsSid;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("errorText", NpgsqlDbType.Text) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value =  error ?? String.Empty;
```

I get the following error:

> context.Error.Message = "42883: function administer_charge(totalCost => numeric, smsLogId => bigint, broadcastId => integer, singleDispatchId => integer, isBroadcast => boolean, userId => text, idempotencyToken => text, smsStatus => integer, externalSMSId => text, errorText => tex...

I believe the problem is here:

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("totalCost", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }).Value=  this.totalSMSCost;
```

The conversion of decimal to numeric.

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue` it will infer the datatype you give it and in this case, is more than likely what's happening. Please use `Add` and specify the datatype... https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html

Comment: `bigint` <> `int`, you probably need to convert `SMSLogId` to `(long)`. But yeah, better just specify the types explicitly, see https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: SMSLogId is long. I will try the solution.

Comment: Please see update

Comment: Do you see an error in the Postgres logs?

Comment: I am not sure how to have a look. All I have is a stack trace of the error. I think, I will opt out of the stored procedure and write a one big multi-stage query.